# SQL getting only the difference two select groups

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I'm working on a `SELECT` in SQL Server, where I try to select the difference of the amount of two groups. I'll try to explain in an example:

Table data is as follows:

```
+-----------+---------+------+-------+----------+-------------------------+
|   Ident   |   Name  |Length| Width | Function | Date                    |
+-----------+---------+------+-------+----------+-------------------------+
|  12345    | Name1   | 2500 |  1000 |        1 | 2019-06-13 22:13:26.197 |
|  12345    | Name1   | 2500 |  1000 |        1 | 2019-06-13 22:16:21.950 |
|  12345    | Name1   | 2500 |  1000 |        2 | 2019-06-13 22:17:49.753 |
|  12345    | Name1   | 2500 |  1000 |        2 | 2019-06-13 22:18:28.807 |
|  12345    | Name1   | 2500 |  1000 |        1 | 2019-06-13 22:19:25.433 |
|  12345    | Name1   | 2500 |  1000 |        2 | 2019-06-13 22:30:41.243 |
|  12345    | Name1   | 2500 |  1000 |        1 | 2019-06-13 22:34:04.517 |
|  12345    | Name1   | 2500 |  1000 |        1 | 2019-06-13 22:38:53.967 |
|  98765    | Name2   | 2500 |  1000 |        1 | 2019-06-13 22:58:15.027 |
|  98765    | Name2   | 2500 |  1000 |        2 | 2019-06-13 23:01:09.607 |
|  98765    | Name2   | 2500 |  1000 |        1 | 2019-06-13 23:04:20.060 |
|  98765    | Name2   | 2500 |  1000 |        1 | 2019-06-13 23:07:27.970 |
|  98765    | Name2   | 2500 |  1000 |        2 | 2019-06-13 23:21:09.703 |
+-----------+---------+------+-------+----------+-------------------------+
```

my desired result, getting two rows of Ident 12345, because there are 8 rows in total which are equal (except Function and Date) - there are five Function=1 and three Function=2 .. so i want 2 rows with the ident 12345 ... which one, doesn't matter.

Same for Ident 98765. there my desired result would be 1 row.

So in total 3 rows with one select

```
- 12345,Name1,2500,1000,1,2019-06-13 22:13:26.197
- 12345,Name1,2500,1000,1,2019-06-13 22:16:21.950
- 98765,Name2,2500,1000,1,2019-06-13 23:21:09.703
```

I don't know if it is possible to set the LIMIT in SQL Server by a select?

Like

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.table 
WHERE Function = 1 
  AND Date > DATEADD(HOUR, -1, GETDATE()) 
LIMIT     'get difference of group count Function=1 and Function=2'
```

The select should only take care where the timestamp is not older than an hour.

Comment: I am still not clear about your criteria to return one row or two rows? By number of rows or what?

Comment: Great job posting sample data and desired output. But I have to agree...the logic for the output is not clear at all.

Comment: Why 2 for 12345 and 1 for 98765?

Comment: the rows are all equal (except Function and timestamp) .. for Ident 12345, there are 8 rows in total, 5 with Function=1, 3 with Function=2 ... so i need the difference (5-3) of Function=1

Comment: For 98765  there are 5 rows in total... 3 rows with Function=1, 2rows with Function=2 ... so there i one row left with Function=1 .. in total that make 3 rows

Comment: Does it means, that all possible values for `Function` column are `1` and `2`?

Comment: i can't garantue that this is the case, but i'm only interessted in these values. and probably there will be only entries with value 1 or 2 in Function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question, next approach may help. Just use `SUM()` as window function and `ROW_NUMBER()`.

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE #Data (
   Ident int,   
   Name varchar(10),
   Length int,
   Width int,
   [Function] int, 
   [Date] datetime                    
)
INSERT INTO #Data 
   (Ident, Name, Length, Width, [Function], [Date])
VALUES
   (12345, 'Name1', 2500, 1000, 1, '2019-06-13T22:13:26.197'),
   (12345, 'Name1', 2500, 1000, 1, '2019-06-13T22:16:21.950'),
   (12345, 'Name1', 2500, 1000, 2, '2019-06-13T22:17:49.753'),
   (12345, 'Name1', 2500, 1000, 2, '2019-06-13T22:18:28.807'),
   (12345, 'Name1', 2500, 1000, 1, '2019-06-13T22:19:25.433'),
   (12345, 'Name1', 2500, 1000, 2, '2019-06-13T22:30:41.243'),
   (12345, 'Name1', 2500, 1000, 1, '2019-06-13T22:34:04.517'),
   (12345, 'Name1', 2500, 1000, 1, '2019-06-13T22:38:53.967'),
   (98765, 'Name2', 2500, 1000, 1, '2019-06-13T22:58:15.027'),
   (98765, 'Name2', 2500, 1000, 2, '2019-06-13T23:01:09.607'),
   (98765, 'Name2', 2500, 1000, 1, '2019-06-13T23:04:20.060'),
   (98765, 'Name2', 2500, 1000, 1, '2019-06-13T23:07:27.970'),
   (98765, 'Name2', 2500, 1000, 2, '2019-06-13T23:21:09.703')
```

Statement:

```
SELECT 
   t.Ident, t.Name, t.Length, t.Width, t.[Function], t.[Date]
FROM (   
   SELECT 
      *,
      SUM(CASE 
             WHEN [Function] = 1 THEN 1 
             WHEN [Function] = 2 THEN -1 
             ELSE 0
          END) OVER (PARTITION BY Ident, Name, Length, Width) AS Cnt,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Ident, Name, Length, Width ORDER BY [Date]) AS Rn  
   FROM #Data
) t
WHERE t.Rn <= t.Cnt
```

Output:

```
Ident   Name    Length  Width   Function    Date
12345   Name1   2500    1000    1           13/06/2019 22:13:26
12345   Name1   2500    1000    1           13/06/2019 22:16:21
98765   Name2   2500    1000    1           13/06/2019 22:58:15
```

Comment: Great. A very elegant solution.

Comment: just that i missed something in my solution a copy of that

Answer (score -1):

You can try using `group by` and limiting group by as per the count difference of function 1 and function 2 of each group

```
  Select  t.Ident, t.Name, t.Length, 
    t.Width, t.[Function], t.[Date]
    from (   Select Ident,   Name , Length,
        ,Width, case when 
   count(function=1)>=count(function=2) 
   then 1
     else
        2
         end case
        , Date, 
     row_number() over( partition by 
      function) as rn,count(function=1)-
       count(function=2) as sum
       from table group by 
        Ident, Name ,Length,
        Width) t where t.rn <=t.sum ;
```

Comment: hmm maybe i missed that above.. but i'm working on MSSQL .. your query doesn't seem to be compatible with that. (e.g. rownumber() is not availble .. and a comparision inside (count) is not valid as well. but thanks a lot for your input

Comment: try with row_number() and what is the error you get

Comment: there are a lot of messages, but e.g. ```'rownumber' is not a recognized built-in function name```

Comment: and with ```count(Function=1)``` i get ```Incorrect snytax near ')'. Expecting ',', AND or OR```

Comment: There are just way too many logical and syntax errors in this.